# Writing a Python Validator function for phone and email

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-validation

I have a website to validate spreadsheet headers and rows when a spreadsheet is uploaded to the site,here i have some validation function where i will have to validate the rows according the attributes of the field in my case i have model like below:

**models.py**

```
from phone_field.models import PhoneField

class Address(BaseModel):
phone = PhoneField(max_length=255, blank=True)
add_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I need to write the custom validators for below

```
def phone_validator(value):
      code:
def city_validator(value):
      code
def add_2(value):
       code
```

Comment: Are you looking to validate any valid phone number or only numbers within a specific country?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: i@bendodge its USA